# Different Price for different group

Tags: magento, product

Can someone help me,

I have a regular price and a attr price that is msrp

How can I have it by editing the codes?

For example, if the user is not login he gets the msrp price

and if log in he gets the regular price.

I'm trying to avoid using any plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With version 1.7 Magento allows "Group Price". Go to your product, click "Price" and then "Add Group Price". Add Group "NOT LOGGED IN" and enter your msrp. The regular price may be entered as the normal price of the product.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but however my client doesn't want to upgrade to 1.7 and want to use the Product attribute MSRP. Any way i can get this through? i tried editing the price.phtml but not able to achieve anything.

Comment: Then use "Tier Price" with quantity 1 for Group "NOT LOGGED IN" and your msrp. But that solution is an abomination

Comment: I was planning to do that as my last option due to having to edit 1000+ products for adding a Tier Price. But i guess i don't have any more option. btw why did you say it's ab abomination?

Comment: You would have to do a lot of frontend editing, bc the shown prices are all messed up. But maybe this helps http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/64833/

Comment: Just what i needed.. one last question though do you have any idea where to find the file to edit? 

Override getPrice method of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price with this code 

Thanks

Comment: /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php 
copy it to /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php and edit the file.

if you know the function, you know the path ;)

Comment: Cool.! Thanks a lot.. Godbless you..! :)